# Pairing data in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

For example, if the following is the data in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'type': ['cat2','cat1','cat2','cat1','cat2',
                 'cat1','cat2','cat1','cat1','cat2'], 
        'values': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,5], 
        'experiment': [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]}
my_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

A paired test is needed between 'cat1' vs. 'cat2' by pairing the data according to 'experiment'. What is the proper way in pandas to do so? I am new to pandas and haven't fully adjusted to thinking about data there.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Probably a data frame that has two columns with the members of the pairs that I can easily access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```
>>> my_data.pivot(index='experiment', columns='type', values='values')


type        cat1  cat2
experiment            
0              2     1
1              1     3
2              3     2
3              2     1
4              3     5
```

Comment: Exactly. I knew there was an elegant way. Thank you.